The expression "в сенях"
I asked a related question on Italian Language StackExchange. In Осень by Pushkin, we have:

Люблю я пышное природы увяданье,
В багрец и в золото одетые леса,
В их сенях ветра шум и свежее дыханье,

On Викисловарь, we have the word сень and the word сени (I consider only се́ни I, since се́ни II is сень declined). I saw here that "В сенях" can be translated by "In the entryway" (which does not seem to make much sense here), I guess that "В сенях" in that sense is сени, while Pushkin probably uses сень here. Nevertheless, I am a bit confused by the use of "В" here, do we have "В их сенях" = "Под их сенью" = "In their shade"?

In this context, сень means "tree crown, part of a canopy (of a forest)".
From Wiktionary:

трад.-поэт. крона или ветви деревьев, образующие полог, шатёр.

Other meanings of this word are "coverage, domination" and "area covered or dominated by something". In these meanings, it's almost always used in oblique cases: в сени́ чего-либо or под се́нью чего либо. These expressions effectively mean the same.
All these meanings are parts of a metonymy chain ("shade" > "coverage" > "something that gives coverage" > "tree crown"), so it can be a little tricky to distinguish between the meanings. Yet other meaning of the word, the plurale tantum сени ("entry hall, porch, coatroom"), adds to the confusion.
However, in this context and with this stress pattern (в их се́нях), it unequivocally means "tree crowns", in the plural.
Now, wind can make rustling sounds in the tree crowns (в се́нях деревьев), under the tree crowns (под се́нями деревьев), or in the area shaded or dominated by trees (в сени́ деревьев or под се́нью деревьев).
In this poem, it does so in the tree crowns, because that's, naturally, the best place for the wind to make rustling sounds. Hence the choice of the stress and the preposition.

СЕНЬ

устар. тень (dated, shade) ◆ Среди Девичьего поля, в сени двух шатров великолепных, стояли два олтаря, богато украшенные; вокруг олтарей духовенство, патриарх, святители с иконами и крестами за духовенством бояре и сановники, в одеждах блестящих серебром и золотом; далее бесчисленное множество людей, ряды конницы и пехоты, с распущенными знамёнами, ляхи и россияне. Карамзин, «История государства Российского», 1824⁠–⁠1826 г. (цитата из НКРЯ)

устар. полог ( dated, cover) ◆ На третьем дворе были также солдаты, стояла целая толпа народа, играла музыка, а посреди тянулась маститая индийская колоннада, в глубине которой на троне из слоновой кости, под пурпуровой сенью, в парчовом одеянии сидел сам раджа. А. Д. Салтыков, «Письма из Индии», 1841 г. (цитата из НКРЯ).


So you can use both prepositions, but the meaning is slightly different: under the cover or in the shade.

"под сенью" became an idiomatic expression meaning "under the shade of tree or trees, always used singular" and is not outdated as such. One just struggle to find any other recent uses of the word.

Thank you very much, your answer is very useful, nevertheless according to the nice explanation by @Quassnoi, it seems that the literal translation of "В их сенях" by "in the shade" is not the best one and "in the tree crowns" seems better. Moreover his answer made me realize that I should have guessed that it could not be the word "сени" just for a matter of stress (I am ashamed to not have realized it before). That's why I am rather inclined to accept his answer.
